# angular cant find toggle function in model

Tags: angular, events, model-driven

I am binding data in model class and looping the data fine. But I failed to bind toggle function in model class to the template click event.

*I created a model to bind the data from a jokelist component and looping the jokes with ngFor directive. 
Created jokerow component and send joke object as input param from jokelist. the properties are working fine. but the function is not detected.*

Model:

```
export interface IJoke {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    hide: boolean;    
}

export interface IJokelist {
    jokeList: IJoke[];
}

export class JokeModel {
    jokeList: IJokelist;
    joke: IJoke;
    hide: boolean;

    constructor(jokeList: IJokelist) {
        this.jokeList = jokeList;
        // this.hide = true;
    }

    getAllProducts(): any {
        return this.jokeList;
    }

    toggle(): void {
        //this.hide = !this.hide;
        console.log('hi');
    }
}
```

**jokelist.Component.ts**

```
export class JokelistComponent implements OnInit {

  jokesList: IJokelist;

  jokesStatic: any = [{ fname: 'chandu', lname: 'm', hide: true },
  { fname: 'venkat', lname: 'p', hide: true },
  { fname: 'ramu', lname: 'b', hide: true }];


  constructor() {
    const newProduct = new JokeModel(this.jokesStatic);
    this.jokesList = newProduct.getAllProducts();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

***jokelist.component.html***

```
<app-jokerow *ngFor="let j of jokesList" [joke]="j"></app-jokerow>
```

**jokerow component**

```
export class JokerowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('joke') data: IJoke;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**jokerow.component.html**

```
<div class="card card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{data.fname}}</h4>     
    <p class="card-text"
     [hidden]="data.hide">{{data.lname}}</p>
  <a (click)="data.toggle()"
     class="btn btn-warning">Tell Me
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toggle function is not specific to your model.

You have to pass data to toggle and then you can show/hide.

```
<a (click)="toggle(data)"
     class="btn btn-warning">Tell Me
  </a>
```

In component,

```
 toggle(data): void {
        data.hide = !data.hide;   //updated
        console.log('hi');
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi is showing in the console. but, the display toggle is not showing the data.

Comment: I updated answer. it should be !data.hide instead of !this.hide

Comment: Tq, its done, but can you tell me why angular did not detect the same function in written in model.

Comment: toggle function isn't part of your model, yur model has just 3 properties, no function.

Comment: JokeModel has toggle function right? and the IJokelist is injected in constructor. You solved my issue but can you help me to understand it why?

Comment: JokeModel is a normal class with toggle function which is called by IJoke(data) model from view, but that function is not part of IJOke. that is why you can't directly call toggle function. If you want to directly call toggle, you have to include it in IJoke interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176641/discussion-between-chandoo-and-dheeraj-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Update `getAllProducts` so jokesList elements will have `toggle` function

```
getAllProducts(): any {
    return this.jokeList.map (j => { 
        j.toggle = this.toggle;
        return j;
    });
}
```

Comment: Muhammed, it didn't worked for me. tq for sparing your time.

Comment: @chandoo no is working I forget  to add return statement for map

Comment: @Mhuammed I made the changes mentioned by you. but, its not working I think some thing more need to be changed or I messed up my  code. Tq